# Symfony2 forms: add delete icon near each element

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

I would like to display in my form a list of elements from the entity. Near each element, it should be a delete button which will delete the specific element from the entty.

Do you know how I could do this?

Example: 3 entities: Person, Affiliation and PersonAffiliations. A person has 0 or many affiliations. Lets say I created 10 affiliations for the person and now I would like to delete one of them. How to create the form in order to display a list of all the affiliations for the specific person and near each affiliation display a small delete icon. When click on this icon, the affiliation should be deleted for this person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to embed a [collection of forms](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) and use a lot of Javascript. It is in the *Symfony2 Cookbook*!

Follow the example with the tags provided in the link above! Its easy, you have to put one anchor with the "*remove*" or "*x*" string per each sub-form to be removed and handle the deletion with Javascript.

Form insertion is done by using the *Prototype* of the subform that you need to add, but seems you don't need insertion.

Notice that in your example you have to create an empty `Person` object and to add to it the list of predefined `Affiliation` object(s) such that the `FormBuilder` will be capable to render the forms related to `Affiliation`. Then you can delete the sub-forms with Javascript.
Of course, it is in general better to define dedicated form types.

---

If you only need to deselect a list of entities that are in relations with the main entity, then you can use the [entity field type](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html) and you can render is as a list of checkboxes with the expanded option. Your controller will bind the entity and the related relationships and so it Symfony will cancel the precedeing relationships.

Comment: Thank you, +1 for you. "BUT", in my entity person, I have a connection with the entity affiliation (OneToMany), so I can find all the affiliations for the person. Why then using collection of forms ?

Comment: Yeah, I understand! If you want to remove the Affiliation you need Javascript. If you only want to select them you can render a select as a list of checkboxes!

Comment: To render the list of affiliations use the entity field and render it as expanded with multiple selection. See more [here].(http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html)

Comment: Are you sure there is no possibility to remove them with symfony, what's about the "collection Field Type" and allow_delete option? See: http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/collection.html#allow-delete

Comment: If you read the cookbook I suggested you will notice that **you have to use the collection form field type**!

Comment: I will take a look on this example but whay nt using the collection Field Type ?

Comment: Moreover, if you don't want to use Javascript, you should render with the collection field type all the affiliations plus a checkbox that states if you want to disable it or not. Then you have to proces this info in the controller. But to do this you have to define a lot of formtypes...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19996/discussion-between-jeanvaljean-and-milos)